# Log android app events

Tags: android, logging, acra

I want to find a good 3rd party tool to use for logging all my android app events and view on a remote server. I only have access to client side of the app with no control of the server side.

I want to track the following from my app:

1. Which screen did users visit
2. What actions he did on the screens(with
   timestamps)
3. Some app specific relation between these events. (the
   app has a bunch of actions together which constitute a meaningful
   event)
4. User Information etc.

I am currently using ACRA + Google docs (old format) for tracking crashes-only. But cannot create any new project using this setup anymore (google doc support deprecated).

Also what would be a good architecture to submit the logs - at every event, group them together.

Comment: Have you tried Rollbar? 
http://www.rollbar.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try google analytics :
http://www.google.com/analytics/
or flurry:
http://www.flurry.com/

Comment: Flurry works best based on my evaluations of various options. The only problem i noticed was that the data is delayed by 10+ hours. I wish they can do something about it.